# dbSNP clarification

Tags: rna-sequencing

I am currently going through this paper - [link](http://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(16)30280-X).
In their methods section the authors have described they have used dbSNP for checking biallelic expression of genes. I would like to know if dbSNP contains SNPs for intergenic regions i.e. for non coding RNA regions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dbSNP is in no way limited to coding SNPs.  One example, an intergenic SNP I found in ensembl.org:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?searchType=adhoc_search&type=rs&rs=rs542978047

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am currently trying to learn as much as possible on the topic.